# What is the next step after writing a .txt doc?

Tags: html

I've been studying htlm and css lately, and wanted to practice so I stated writing one txt.
I have put the txt and the image used in the same folder. I'm not sure what to do next though... I've tried reading online, but I couldn't find anything. 
DISCLAIMER: I know this might be a very trivial question, but then again it's better to ask and learn, right? :) Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try renaming the .txt file to a .html file.  You may be able to this through Windows Explorer if you can see extensions, or you may have to do it at the command line.

One way could be: 
Open the .txt file in Notepad
Go to "Save as..."
Change the drop down of the type from *.txt (Text) to * (All Files)
enter a filename and remember to put **.html** on the end.

Thanks,

Comment: if i was give by my school for example, a subdomain, how could i open my .html from there?